# How to remove commas in a column within a Pyspark Dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Hi all thanks for the time to help me on this,

Right now I have uploaded a csv into spark and the type of the dataframe is `pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame`

I have a column of numbers (that are strings in this case though). They are numbers like `6,000` and I just want to remove all the commas from these numbers. I have tried `df.select("col").replace(',' , '')` and `df.withColumn('col', regexp_replace('col', ',' , '')` but seem to be getting an error that *"DataFrame Object does not support item assignment"*

Any ideas? I'm fairly new to Spark

Answer (score 1):

You should be casting it really:

```py
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType
df = df.withColumn("col", df["col"].cast(IntegerType()))
```

Comment: that actually returns nulls to me if I try doing it that way

Comment: then there must be non numeric data in your column values, that is why you are getting Null .... In that case you will need to use UDF to deal with whatever non numeric values is present .... Show your table data if you need further advice....